# Debian package with optional files

Tags: debian, packaging

Scripts to create debian package exist and work. I have to modify them.
In new specific case there may be some optional files which I want to include to package.

If I add them to package.install, then I fail as only those file don't exist.
If I don't add them to package.install, then they will never be included to package even if they exist.

To determine specific case I have special environment variable: `SPECIFIC_CASE=CASE`

How should I set up debian package creation scripts to search for those files just in case of specific case?

In file `rules` (which is designed as Makefile) I have targets:

```
copy_files:
override_dh_install:
override_dh_auto_install: (empty)
...list of other overrides...
install:
postbuild:
clean:
```

Comment: What does your `debian/rules` look like? Does it mostly just use debhelper (`dh`)? Does it override it (e.g., `override_dh_auto_install`, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, `rules` contains targets with overrride_* name pattern. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With most packaging tools in Debian, the contents of the a package `package` end up being whatever is in `debian/package` when `dpkg-deb` is run. You can place files there in whichever way you want, you don’t have to rely on `dh_install` (which is the tool which processes `.install` files).

Thus:

```
override_dh_install:
        dh_install
        install blah debian/package/wherever
```

and so on. This is where you’d add your conditional file handling.

**However** it’s important to realise that a packaging specification (and this isn’t specific to Debian) should be consistent: *i.e.* on a given architecture, building a package should always result in the same package contents. Packaging optional content usually involves building the project so that all the files are generated, and then dispatching them into different packages, not all of which need to be installed. (This *can* involve going to great lengths, *e.g.* the GCC build which has a few tricks so that the compiler driver knows about all the available languages but they don’t all have to be installed.)

Comment: So your suggestion is to create additional package for optional files?
My idea was to create specific debug version with coverage (`*.gcov`) files, so our jenkins would use it as for usual tests, but we would get additional coverage info from it. 
And for that task, I would like to make the whole process transparent, controlling the process by explicit environment variable

Comment: Yes. For coverage you’d end up with two builds, driven by `debian/rules` in all cases: one with the usual build, building the standard package, and another with `-O0 --coverage`, building a `-coverage` package (with the `.gcno` files). See [the `dosbox` `debian/rules`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/dosbox/blob/master/debian/rules) for a similar example (standard package and debugger-enabled package).